# How to get the closest match among three numbers

Tags: python, numbers

I have a list :

```
[(1, 49, 47), (11, 44, 6), (24, 16, 31), (11, 29, 47), (41, 14, 24), (40, 29, 1), (32, 49, 44), (41, 14, 14), (24, 21, 49), (19, 24, 6)]
```

And a tuple `(7,2,3)` I need to choose a value from this list such that every element in the tuple should be less than or equal to the new value selected according to their positions, for example, if I select `(19, 24, 6)`, the condition is true as

```
7 <= 19
2 <= 24
3 <= 6
```

How can I select the new tuple such that the individual values are minimum.

If I assume the numbers have a higher weightage towards left, I can sort them based on first element, then the second...

But is there are better way to do this? if the numbers did not have any weightage according to their position?

Comment: have you already tried list comprehension with the needed condition?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `all` and a nested comprehension:

```
data = [(1, 49, 47), (11, 44, 6), (24, 16, 31), (11, 29, 47), (41, 14, 24), (40, 29, 1), (32, 49, 44), (41, 14, 14), (24, 21, 49), (19, 24, 6)]
find = 7,2,3

result = [t for t in data if all(x <= y for x, y in zip(find, t))]
```

---

```
[(11, 44, 6), (24, 16, 31), (11, 29, 47), (41, 14, 24), (32, 49, 44), (41, 14, 14), (24, 21, 49), (19, 24, 6)]
```

If you want the first one that satisfies the condition, then you can use `next`

```
result = next(t for t in data if all(x <= y for x, y in zip(find, t)))
# use random.choice instead to get a random one instead of the first
```

---

```
(11, 44, 6)
```

Comment: This should work, but taking linear distance in to account, `(19,24,6)` seems closer.

Comment: So is there a different way to do it?